# How to use RequestAnimationFrame correctly？

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made a diffuse animation and used RequestAnimationFrame to achieve it.I tried hundreds of times to improve my program.But it doesn't work!!!Where's my wrong?

```
function draw_point(x, y){
    x += 10.5;
    y += 10.5;
    radius = 0;
    var context = $("#canvas_graph")[0].getContext('2d');
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(render(x, y, radius, context));
};

function drawCircle(x, y, radius, context){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.closePath();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    context.stroke();
    radius += 0.2;

    if (radius > 10) {
        radius = 0;
        }
};

//The effect of diffusion is achieved by changing the attribute
function render(x ,y, radius, context){
    return function step(){
        var prev = context.globalCompositeOperation;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
        context.globalAlpha = 0.95;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 890, 890);
        context.globalCompositeOperation = prev;
        drawCircle(x, y, radius,context);

        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(step);
    };  
};
draw_point(100， 100)；
```

But this can be used normally.Function render through the globalAlpha attribute so that the circle is getting lighter.Newly drawn circles are getting bigger.Small rounds are becoming lighter and lighter by using the globalAlpha property again and again.

```
var context = $("#canvas_graph")[0].getContext('2d');
var radius = 0;
var x = 100;
var y = 100;
function drawCircle(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.closePath();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    context.stroke();
    radius += 0.2;

if (radius > 10) {
    radius = 0;
    }
};
function render(){
    var prev = context.globalCompositeOperation;
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
    context.globalAlpha = 0.95;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 890, 890);
    context.globalCompositeOperation = prev;
    drawCircle();

    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(render);
};
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(render);
```

In addition,when canvas animation move up, how to restore the background?

Comment: What issue are you having with `javascript` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 The first program does not show anything, and the second can show the animation correctly. The difference between the two is the first program more than a function call.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your `draw_point` function like so. What you have currently is executing the `render` function right away, you want to pass a reference to `requestAnimationFrame`, not inserting a function call there

```
function draw_point(x, y){
    x += 10.5;
    y += 10.5;
    radius = 0;
    var context = $("#canvas_graph")[0].getContext('2d');
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(function() {
        render(x, y, radius, context));
    }
};
```